# CSS div dynamic height

Tags: css

I have two divs as shown below (A and B):

[image]

Section B is has an input field with max-height of 100px (as an example) and overflow-y auto: This way, the input field will only be certain height.

```
.section_B{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;   
   width: 100%;
}
.section_B_input{
   max-height: 100px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Because Section B's height can be anywhere in between 20px and 100px (for example), the section A's height needs to be dynamic and is depended on Section B height.

I read that display:flex can be used somehow, but I am not sure how to.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique with flexbox is to add `flex-grow: 1;` to the element you want to have a dynamic height. Here is a quick example.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
html,body,.flex {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #eee;
}
.b {
  background: #333;
}
section {
  padding: 2em;
}
input {
  transition: padding .5s;
}
input:focus {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <section class="a">
  </section>
  <section class="b">
    <input>
  </section>
</div>
```